# Linked API for get Company Post

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have tried to use the API for linkedin company posts.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/activityFeeds?q=networkShares&count=2&oauth2_access_token={mytoken}
```

But i am getting this error.

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-networkShares /activityFeeds","status":403}
```

I guess i need some extra permission to get response. I have the "client id" and "secret id". So can i get the company posts by any other API ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to use application authorization via OAuth 2 then you will need to generate an access token along with your client ID & secret. This can then be attempted to the request via Basic authorization.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-2022-07) should explain that in more detail

Comment: I have the access token. How can i use those ?

Comment: If you provide a code sample of the request I can be more specific but in step 3 of the linked article you can add the token to the `Authorization` header of your outgoing request.

It is likely *Basic* Auth but you may have to play around with the [scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?view=li-lms-unversioned&tabs=http